# Sonar Kotlin Object 0% coverage

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, sonarqube

In my project I created an object to hold some Constants to be used along the project modules, for example, Success/Error messages, but when I run the Sonar scan, it reports the file with 0% coverage.

I tried to test the constants values to check if Sonar would see that as covered, but it didn't, actually it does show the `object Messages {}` as not covered, not the lines inside:

[image: Sonar report image]

How can I cover it with tests so Sonar won't report it as 0% covered?

Comment: Why is it a problem ?

Comment: Why it is not? It will decrease my code coverage, line coverage, new code coverage, etc, etc

Comment: Well this coverage is a bit pointless, especially if you try to add test only for the sake of more coverage. It doesn't bring any value

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but in some cases we need this kind of test, just to increase the coverage, in my case, everytime we commit some new version where the Sonar runs, it need 95%+ new code coverage, and in my case, this case was decreasing it a lot, but indeed, it has no value as a real test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest way to fix it, was to create a test to check if the object is not null

Using Kotlin and JUnit

```
val obj = Messages
assertNotNull(obj)
```